# Access on-premise web API (endpoints) from web app deployed in Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, on-premises-instances

On-premise API do not use public URL. Both applications (on-premise API and Azure web app) are registered under same Azure AD (single tenant). My app will be used by 50 or more concurrent users. I would like to know if I can use Hybrid connection in this scenario ?

I checked the below link. I have a doubt if I could use Hybrid connection as it comes under multi tenant app service networking features (and ASE for single tenant)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features

May I know what would be appropriate App service networking feature to connect on-premise API and azure web app. Thank you.

Comment: Please check this MS link you can use External ASE or ILB ASE networking feature to access the on-prem WebAPI from Azure Apps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info

Comment: Thank you. Can you pls explain why Hybrid connection cannot be used in my case. I notice that App Service Environment is a fully isolated and dedicated environment for running Azure apps at high scale(for advanced networking and scale). Mine will be less demanding workload mostly.

Comment: Hybrid Connections is popular for development, but it's also used in production applications. It's great for accessing a web service or database, but it's not appropriate for situations that involve creating many connections.

Comment: And In ASE you don't need to do any additional configuration(Like VNET Integration). If you want to access resources across ExpressRoute, you're already in the virtual network and don't need to configure anything on the ASE or the apps in it.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, since 50 or more concurrent users would be accessing my application, which involves creating many connections. Which is why Hybrid is not suitable in this case.

Comment: Yes Correct. That i had mentioned in second comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main deployment types for Azure App Service

1. The multitenant public service hosts App Service plans in the Free, Shared, Basic, Standard, Premium, PremiumV2, and PremiumV3 pricing SKUs.
2. The single-tenant App Service Environment (ASE) hosts Isolated SKU App Service plans directly in your Azure virtual network.

Hybrid Connections is popular for development, but it's also used in production applications. It's great for accessing a web service or database, but it's not appropriate for situations that involve creating many connections

This feature is commonly used to:

> • Access resources in private networks that aren't connected to Azure
> with a VPN or ExpressRoute.

And In ASE you don't need to do any additional configuration (Like VNET Integration because the ASE is already in your virtual network.). If you want to access resources across ExpressRoute, you're already in the virtual network and don't need to configure anything on the ASE or the apps in it.

**So Best Option is based on above point is to use ASE (Single Tenant).**

For establishing Hybrid connect it require to for addition relay agent in the network that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint and where in ASE it doesn’t require such things.

Reference from MS DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features